# Why am i getting "unresolved identifier" when using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

This is super frustrating because i've looked at code examples from very recent answers, tutorials, etc. on how to create a send email function (using the built in ios mail) and it's throwing me errors. Specifically, unresolved use of "self identifier" and "present"

```
func sendEmail(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailVC.setToRecipients([])
    mailVC.setSubject("Subject for email")
    mailVC.setMessageBody("Email message string", isHTML: false)

    presentViewController(mailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

what example am i doing wrong? Logically, it makes sense; i've created an instance of mailcompose and then assigned its delegate to itself.

looked at these two for use:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-send-an-email
[Sending an email from swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887721/sending-an-email-from-swift-3)

Comment: What version of Xcode and Swift are you using? And please include complete and exact error messages in your question and point out exactly which line is causing the error.

Comment: I did not criticize. I simply asked you to provide further details to make it easier for people to help you. And you should not make assumptions about whether I down voted or not.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add `import MessageUI`, and you’ll also need to conform to the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Both errors you reported hint that your `sendEmail` function might have been declared *outside* a view controller class (i.e., it's a global function). If this is the case, move it to the appropriate `UIViewController` subclass instead ;)

As correctly pointed out by Nemanja's answer, be sure to import `MessageUI` framework as well.