# How to send email in swift without the user having to press send?

Tags: ios, email

Know a user can send a mail using he `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887721/sending-an-email-from-swift-3), but how to send a conformation mail to the user after the set of specific task has been done.

For some reason it feels like apple doesn't allow in sending background mails, without user conformation, which is fine.

The task is to send a conformation mail like after you buy productA, productB and pay, need to send a receipt to the said mail id.

Any guide in the said path would be greatly appericiated

Comment: The email would need to be sent from your server, not the client app. Are you collecting the user's email address and being notified of the purchase event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send an email **from** the user's email address without using an `MFMailComposeViewController`, and you can't send an email **to** the user without the use of a server.

What you should do is prompt the user to enter their email address, send that as part as their purchase, and then use a server-side mail app to send a confirmation email to the user-provided email address.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send it directly from users device without email composer.

Only way to do this will be to prepare your own server that will handle those events and send proper emails from server side.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about sending an email to the user, not from the user.

Comment: Still answer remains the same :) only way to send is server side